# Shutterfly Order API . 

Tags: asp.net, api

I found this site

http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/api_OrderImage.sfly

but there are no examples of actually walking through the whole process.  Does anyone have any good documentation on using this API to take a local photo and allow someone to order a print via shutterfly?

Comment: Have you looked here? http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/api_ExplorerImageUpload.sfly Seems easy enough.

Comment: Do you want to upload the photo to your (your company's) shutterfly account and print from your own account or do you want to have the user create/use their own account to upload to and print from?

Comment: user create its own account.  so my friend can go on my site and choose a picture and have it printed with shutterfly

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I went through these steps:

- [Sign up for an account](https://www.shutterfly.com/signup/viewSignup.sfly)
- [Sign up as a developer](https://www.shutterfly.com/developer/apps.sfly)

Create an application (I called mine Test). Note the generated **Application Id** and **Shared Secret**

The [Shutterfly API page](http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/start.sfly) has a list of references for various Domain-specific APIs:

- [Address Book](http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/api_AddressBook.sfly)
- [Album Data](http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/api_Album.sfly)
- [Folder Data](http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/api_Folder.sfly)
- [Go To Shutterfly UE](http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/api_ImageUpload.sfly)
- [Image Upload](http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/IsiSetup.sfly)
- [Interactive Sign-in](http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/api_Proctaserv.sfly)
- [Image Request](http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/api_Order.sfly)
- [Order](http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/api_Order.sfly)
- [Pricing](http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/api_Pricing.sfly)
- [Seamless Sign-in](http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/SsiSetup.sfly)
- [User Data](http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/api_User.sfly)
- [User Authentication](http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/api_UserAuth.sfly)

Each uses RESTful principles. The documentation looks pretty comprehensive to me, if you need some background, here's links for [RESTful](http://www.xfront.com/REST-Web-Services.html) APIs and [ROME](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/02/22/rome-parse-publish-rss-atom-feeds-java.html) you may find useful

There is also an **API Explorer** section on the same page that allows you to test the methods via a form on their site. For example this form for [CRUD operations on the album data](https://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/api_ExplorerAlbum.sfly).

Based on your comment, for your requirements, you would:

- Use the [Album GET](http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/api_Album.sfly#GET) to list albums, then get the data for a specific album.
- Use the [Image Get](http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/api_Proctaserv.sfly#GET) request to retrieve the image data, so your friend can verify the image(s) they want to purchase.
- [Authenticate the user](http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/AuthAuth.sfly)
- Use the [Pricing POST](http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/api_Pricing.sfly#POST) request to get the estimated pricing for the image.
- User the [Order POST](http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/api_Order.sfly#POST) to submit the order over https

---

Update: Found a page [describing](http://quasistoic.org/ts/archives/2005/06/22/flickr-shutterfly/) using a Greasemonkey script which adds Shutterfly print ordering capability to Flickr. This might provide the basis for a solution.

Comment: this sounds like it would be useful for the owner of the pictures but i want to have people click on my site and have them order for themselves

Comment: That is what it is intended for. Once the user has signed up, they can browse/select your pictures with this approach

Comment: Read the section on authentication (http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/AuthAuth.sfly) It specifically talks about sharing you application "secret" with authenticated users so they can see your photos

Comment: @oo does this make sense to you or do you need some elaboration?

Answer (score 0):

For Reference:

The original link above is a middle step of the Shutterfly Open API ordering procedure.

The whole process goes through a series of steps allowing you to control much more than just pushing photos into somebody's album in Shutterfly.

With this process, your application can actually carry out the entire procedure of:

- specifying the images and the sizes and quantities, or other products
- calculating shipping, taxes, and totals
- paying, and
- launching the processing

It also includes the ability to see when the packages will be delivered and arrive.

Thus if you have a solid application for mapping your images onto paper and products, you can pretty much control the entire process.

Once the order is submitted, it will appear on the user's account at Shutterfly who the order was associated with.

*Kudos to Shutterfly for making such a powerful tool!  It would be great if other printing facilities had similar tools.*

Comment: I'm in the process of developing a Python wrapper for the system and am hung up on this exact step.  If anybody has any solutions, please see my other post!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785496/a-python-wrapper-for-shutterfly-uploading-an-image   Thanks!