# Shutterfly API Source code samples

Tags: api

Does anyone worked with Shutterfly API? If yes, please share your experience and also please share any sample source code which you have..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275130/shutterfly-order-api) on the subject. Not sure if this is a new post or not but Shutterfly has a sample program in Java [here](http://www.shutterfly.com/documentation/SampleJava1.sfly). These should be a good starting point.